# Deterministic finite automaton for even zeroes and ones in multiples of 5

Tags: automata, dfa

Given a binary string, create a DFA to check if the number of zeroes is even and the number of ones is a multiple of 5.

Answer (score 0):

States are named as 1,2,.... . Given below is the link to state transition table.Green colored are the accepting states.

https://scontent-sin1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpt1/v/t34.0-12/11925945_696377550492948_1087492545_n.jpg?oh=42f1caf85270d92acc48aa5b44c150d9&oe=55D93C98